# Why doesn't this javascript string code work in internet explorer 7?

Tags: jquery, arrays, string, internet-explorer-7

I have the following code that works fine in IE8, firefox, chrome but not in IE7

Can someone please explain why this code below doesn't work in IE7 ?

```
  var myString = $(this).attr("id");
  var nextStep = myString [myString.length - 1];
```

basically, IE7 doesn't seem to understand this line:

```
   myString [myString.length - 1]
```

In this case myString  is just a regular string that i am parsing out from the id of a div.

Comment: What do you mean by "not understand"? Does myString have the correct content? Is the length what you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE7 does not recognize indexing a string in that way. You need to use `myString.charAt(myString.length - 1)`.

Array-like indexing of a string was added to ECMAScript 5, which was released well after IE7 was. [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access)